# How add Form from image clicked in react native?

Tags: forms, react-native

i'm new in react native, i want to add form in the bottom if clicked image in react native. this is my code

```
<View>
     <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this._addForm()}>
                      <Image source={require('../images/plus.png')} />
     </TouchableHighlight>
</View>

{this._addForm()}
```

this function

```
 _addForm(){
             <View>
                <TextInput 
                autoCorrect={false} 
                style={styles.inputVal} 
                onChangeText={(category) => this.setState({category})}/>
              </View>
  }
```

please help. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be the following:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this._toggleForm = this._toggleForm.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            showForm: false,
        };
    }

    _toggleForm() {
        this.setState({
            showForm: !this.state.showForm
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <View>
                    <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._toggleForm}>
                        <Image source={require('../images/plus.png')} />
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                </View>
                {this.state.showForm ?
                <View>
                    // Add your form here
                </View>
                : null }
            </View>
        )
    }

}

module.exports = MyComponent;
```

There are other ways of doing it as well.